# Use of init(contentsOfFile:encoding:) Swift 4

Tags: swift

I want to get a string from a file. I've researched how to do it, and I've found the next code:

```
import Foundation

// Read data from this file.
let path = "/Users/samallen/file.txt"

do {
    // Use contentsOfFile overload.
    // ... Specify ASCII encoding.
    // ... Ignore errors.
    var data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path,
        encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)

    // If a value was returned, print it.
    print(data)
}
```

The important part are the lines:

```
var data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path,
            encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
```

I looked in Apple's documentation about this and found init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:)

What I don't get is why you can use String(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:) instead of init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:). Why can you replace String for init? I have seen somthing similar with UIImage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also use `NSString.init(contentsOfFile: "", encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)`

Comment: @zhangzhi Do you know where in the documentation says that I can use String instead of init? Or why I can replace it?

Comment: Avoid comments like  `// Use contentsOfFile overload", `// Specify ASCII encoding` ... Yeah, we can see that, it's clearly there... `NSString(contentsOfFile:...`, `encoding: String.Encoding.ascii`,...

Comment: @LucianoFalco https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285  `Initializing an Empty String`  `initializer syntax`

Comment: `NSString(` is a short version for `NSString.init(`. It is preferred to use the short version.